# django username restriction list with django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth for user registration and I would like to forbid users from creating specific usernames from a list[]. The list would include names from my url patterns, admin, root, profanity, etc.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is built into [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

> ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST (=[])
>       A list of usernames that can’t be used by user.